# iOS reducing size of binary in App Store update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an application that is currently in the App Store.
It has approximately 500mb of data that it needs in order to run.

I was fighting and fighting various methods to install this data after the app was downloaded, including [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and [WhiteRaccoon](https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon), to no avail... the deadline was coming fast, so I decided to just *ahem* bundle the content into the App Bundle, and worry about it later. This meant the size of the app dictated that people downloaded it while on WiFi, but ... whatever.

Now, I have discovered [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html), much to my delight, and it does everything that I need that I couldn't make the others do (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26456956/1226095) to this question).

So... I am ready to push a new update to the App Store, and my Archive size has been reduced from **491.2mb** to **32.2mb** (!!?woohoo?!!).

I am curious how Apple manages this. I have read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1779/_index.html) that mentions techniques that they use to keep the app bundle size down by detecting what hasn't changed, but it doesn't explicitly mention anything about the scenario that I am facing.

Now, if 460mb or so of obsolete bundle/code is going to be stored in the user's device, I'd like to be able to recommend to them that they delete the app entirely and reinstall... but I am curious if I/they need to do this, or does anyone know how Apple will handle this scenario ?

Thanks.

Comment: Congrats on reducing your app size. Your new design sounds way better. Users don't need to delete and reinstall your app. The App Store diff package will delete this content (unless you programmatically copied it into a directory that persists, like Documents).

Comment: Well, the original content was just copied into the App Bundle. The new content - currently - is in the Documents directory, but not the global one, it is inside the App Sandbox...

Comment: So, going forward, as the content has been copied into the Documents folder, if I delete the app and re-install, I should see the files? Cause I'm not seeing that behaviour... (I query for the custom directory I make inside of /Documents and test if I have all of the content pieces before I start the downloads)

Comment: aka .... I know files in the Documents persists, but the content was part of the bundle before, and is only *now* in the Documents ... So, will the whole bundle be intelligently replaced ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Bottom line, the bundle is effectively replaced. The Documents folder is unchanged.

Comment: I just want to make sure: You're not trying to download tons of data when the user first loads the app, are you? Apple has allegedly rejected apps that downloaded too much data over cellular when the user first fires up the app. If you're downloading the data in a just-in-time manner or with their permission, you're fine. But if you try to do a bulk download (over cellular), you might run afoul of Apple internal guidelines. (I have to confess that I've never see this app download limitation documented, but just some old stories about apps being rejected for using too much cellular bandwidth.)

Comment: @Rob (wow, you must have been on SO for a long time with that name!) No, my configuration for NSURLSession specifies WiFi only, and I prompt the user with an Alert... but good catch, and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document you reference, [Technical Q&A QA1779: Reducing Download Size for iOS App Updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1779/_index.html), covers what Apple does to optimize the size of the app update. But the net effect is the same as if the app bundle on the user's device was entirely replaced. As that document says:

> In addition to new content, the update package contains instructions on how to transform the prior version of the app into the new version of the app. New files will be added, modified files will be replaced with their updated counterpart, and deleted files will be removed as part of this transformation. As far as the developer and user are concerned, this process is entirely transparent and the resulting updated app will be indistinguishable from a full download of the corresponding updated version of their app.

So, no, you don't have to tell users to delete the old app unless there's anything in persistent storage (Documents, `NSUserDefaults`, etc.), that need to be reset. And you should probably handle that programmatically, anyway.

Comment: Ok, didn't catch that wording on first pass... thanks.

Comment: Shameless plug from someone with less than 80k reputation - I'd love to see some upvotes for a responsible question! ;-)